# How did Dani-commander know of Carl?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-dark-fate

In *Terminator: Dark Fate*, Dani-commander in 2042 arranged for Carl's GPS coordinates to be burned on Grace's body (before sending her back in 2020) and told her to go there in case she needed help.

Assuming that the events in 2042 belong to a slightly different timeline (in that Dani-commander did not actually have to be saved from the Rev-9 22 years prior), how did she know about Carl?

Is it assumed that Dani-2042 somehow have met Carl in her past and so in that he had a different story to what was shown in the movie?

Disclaimer: I am not holding my breath regarding Terminator time travel stories (like any other time travel) making consistent sense. After all, time travel *back* in time is neither theoretically possible nor even eventually/logically coherent. But I am just questioning what could possibly the creators of the movie expect the audience to think on this question, if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this film, the events that happen in the present do not alter the timeline in any way. I'm only referring to where the movie begins and not the previous timelines.

Dark Fate is set in a timeline that is a result of Terminator 1 and Terminator 2. The movies that came after T2 can be completely ignored.

So, in Dark Fate, we have this one timeline that has little John dying 3 years after the events of Terminator 2. The events of the movie do not alter the future in anyway. The future sends a Terminator and the humans send Grace. Both Grace and the Terminator die without changing any events of the future.

Dani will eventually meet and save young Grace. She will send Grace back with the coordinates of Carl. How does Dani know the Coordinates of Carl? Well because back in 2020 she visited those exact coordinates to run into Carl.

Comment: So, you essentially say that when Dani saves young Grace in the ruins, she already knows that she will send her back in time several years later? And then, in the deleted scene where Grace asks Dani to send her, Dani has already anticipated her asking so? She knows that Grace will die so she drops tears? The only problem I have with this interpretation is that at the end of the film, when Dani and Sarah see young Grace on the playground, Dani says "_I won't let her die for me again_".

Comment: yes, that's right. And regarding the last line, Dani thinks he will not, but in the end she has no other option. Grace will convince Dani to let her travel back to the past in a one way mission (just like we are shown in the film).